# RSS feed reader using Jquery & codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, rss, rss-reader

Hey I want to create an rss feed reader on my homepage. I want to make it like a news ticker, in which the the news slide one by one. Is there any Jquery plugin that provide this functionality, I came across one plugin but it can extract feed from the same domain not from other domains and I want to get the feeds from here

```
http://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/tops/index.rss
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can combine various JQuery plugin in order to do what you want. For example (and doing a quickly search in Google), there is a plugin called [jGFeed](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com.es/2009/05/google-feeds-api-jquery-plugin.html) that returns all information about an specific feed (you can read the documentation on the link provided).

With all of this information, you can extract what you want (post content, post title, date, etc) and use some other plugin (like [Compact News Previewer](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/03/compact-news-previewer/) [[example](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CompactNewsPreviewer/)]) to display the post.

Comment: thanks a lot sir.. your answer just simply saved a lots of time for me..